# jquery parseJSON handling php errors

Tags: php, jquery

Is there any clever way of handling php errors returned in the data object. Currently I occasionally get things like:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error'
.....
```

this is generally followed by the json object I'm expecting. Is there any systematic way to look for these errors? An example call I'm using might be:

```
function getMyCharities(callback) {
$.post("my_file.php", function(data) {
    callback(data);
});
}
```

In the documentation for jquery I've found:

```
 .done(function() { alert("second success"); }) 
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
```

but these don't handle this type of error as I've tested it. I also don't want to build a error parser if possible.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to handle these errors is to turn off error reporting in PHP. **You should not have error reporting turned on for a production site.**

With error reporting turned off, all PHP errors will return a `HTTP 500` server error which will then be caught by the `fail` callback of your `$.post` promise object.

Answer (score 0):

I think those success/fail methods are with respect to the ajax call made to the server. In your case, the server is returning data with the correct http status. You would need to parse the 'data' object directly on successful callback, to check for signs of failure,
(json flag based ({isFailure: 1}) or worst case, string based). If not, you would need the server to somehow fail, so then when the ajax call is made, the call would fail, and you can handle this in the 'fail' callback on the page.